# fixing this prime generator

Tags: c++

The program below is meant to print prime numbers between the given set of numbers. But when i run, it didn't print out prime numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()

{
int a;
int b;
int z = 0;
cout << "Enter an integer: ";
cin >> a;

cout << "Enter another number: ";
cin >> b;

for (int i=a; i<=b; i++)
{
    for (int j=2; j<i; j++)
    {

        if (i%j == 0)
        {
            z++ ;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (z == 0)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
  }

}
```

[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sKOR.png)
i expect the output to be 2 3 5 7

Comment: Have you used debugger and step through the code?

Comment: At the very least, you can print the value of `z` at different points of your code to see what's happening.

Comment: z=0 at the start.  Then  as soon as z++ happens z>0.  After that z==0 will always be false.

Comment: can you provide current inputs and outputs and your expected output? I don't understand what exactly do you want to achieve

Comment: on entering a=2 b=9     **expected output:-** 2 3 5 7    **actual output:-** 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: @JerryJeremiah actually it will only happen if the number has other factor which divide it completely without leaving reminder and the number will not be prime in that case

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: @user10018410 z=0 is set before the outside loop.  So if 'a' is not prime then none of the numbers above it will be detected because z will not be 0 any longer.  z=0 must be set inside the outside loop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this snippet. Instead of variable z, I use a variable bool prime:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a;
    int b;

    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> b;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j<i; j++)
        {

            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prime)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
```